# Coldfusion Ajax Request Dump Not Rendered in Chrome Anymore

Tags: google-chrome, coldfusion, railo

Before, when debugging my ajax requests in Chrome, if I did a cfdump and cfabort behind the scenes, Chrome would render that dump structure correctly in the developer tools preview pane.

However, within the last week, this has stopped working and instead of rendering the dump, it now just displays the text and actually looks like it's trying to parse the output as json / javascript.

I don't know if this is a chrome setting, or something that has changed in the latest update to Chrome. It definitely worked up until very recently.

*EDIT*: *I can confirm that it does this for Railo as well, so this is definitely a Chrome issue and not a CF/Railo issue*

This is what I dump behind the scenes: `<cfdump var="#ArrayNew(1)#"><cfabort>`

This is what I expect to see and usually saw before:
[image]

This is what I now see:
[image]

Any help would really be appreciated as it is making testing extremely difficult. 
Thanks

EDIT: I have attached the Response body below as requested.

```
        <!-- Login Authentication -->


        <!-- Initial validation and authentication -->

            <!-- Main API Calls -->

                    <!-- FUNCTION calls -->
                    <style>


    table.cfdump_wddx,
    table.cfdump_xml,
    table.cfdump_struct,
    table.cfdump_varundefined,
    table.cfdump_array,
    table.cfdump_query,
    table.cfdump_cfc,
    table.cfdump_object,
    table.cfdump_binary,
    table.cfdump_udf,
    table.cfdump_udfbody,
    table.cfdump_udfarguments {
        font-size: xx-small;
        font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
        cell-spacing: 2px;
    }

    table.cfdump_wddx th,
    table.cfdump_xml th,
    table.cfdump_struct th,
    table.cfdump_varundefined th,
    table.cfdump_array th,
    table.cfdump_query th,
    table.cfdump_cfc th,
    table.cfdump_object th,
    table.cfdump_binary th,
    table.cfdump_udf th,
    table.cfdump_udfbody th,
    table.cfdump_udfarguments th {
        text-align: left;
        color: white;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    table.cfdump_wddx td,
    table.cfdump_xml td,
    table.cfdump_struct td,
    table.cfdump_varundefined  td,
    table.cfdump_array td,
    table.cfdump_query td,
    table.cfdump_cfc td,
    table.cfdump_object td,
    table.cfdump_binary td,
    table.cfdump_udf td,
    table.cfdump_udfbody td,
    table.cfdump_udfarguments td {
        padding: 3px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        vertical-align : top;
    }

    table.cfdump_wddx {
        background-color: #000000;
    }
    table.cfdump_wddx th.wddx {
        background-color: #444444;
    }


    table.cfdump_xml {
        background-color: #888888;
    }
    table.cfdump_xml th.xml {
        background-color: #aaaaaa;
    }
    table.cfdump_xml td.xml {
        background-color: #dddddd;
    }

    table.cfdump_struct {
        background-color: #0000cc ;
    }
    table.cfdump_struct th.struct {
        background-color: #4444cc ;
    }
    table.cfdump_struct td.struct {
        background-color: #ccddff;
    }

    table.cfdump_varundefined {
        background-color: #CC3300 ;
    }
    table.cfdump_varundefined th.varundefined {
        background-color: #CC3300 ;
    }
    table.cfdump_varundefined td.varundefined {
        background-color: #ccddff;
    }

    table.cfdump_array {
        background-color: #006600 ;
    }
    table.cfdump_array th.array {
        background-color: #009900 ;
    }
    table.cfdump_array td.array {
        background-color: #ccffcc ;
    }

    table.cfdump_query {
        background-color: #884488 ;
    }
    table.cfdump_query th.query {
        background-color: #aa66aa ;
    }
    table.cfdump_query td.query {
        background-color: #ffddff ;
    }


    table.cfdump_cfc {
        background-color: #ff0000;
    }
    table.cfdump_cfc th.cfc{
        background-color: #ff4444;
    }
    table.cfdump_cfc td.cfc {
        background-color: #ffcccc;
    }


    table.cfdump_object {
        background-color : #ff0000;
    }
    table.cfdump_object th.object{
        background-color: #ff4444;
    }

    table.cfdump_binary {
        background-color : #eebb00;
    }
    table.cfdump_binary th.binary {
        background-color: #ffcc44;
    }
    table.cfdump_binary td {
        font-size: x-small;
    }
    table.cfdump_udf {
        background-color: #aa4400;
    }
    table.cfdump_udf th.udf {
        background-color: #cc6600;
    }
    table.cfdump_udfarguments {
        background-color: #dddddd;
        cell-spacing: 3;
    }
    table.cfdump_udfarguments th {
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        color: #000000;
    }

</style> <script language="javascript">


// for queries we have more than one td element to collapse/expand
    var expand = "open";

    dump = function( obj ) {
        var out = "" ;
        if ( typeof obj == "object" ) {
            for ( key in obj ) {
                if ( typeof obj[key] != "function" ) out += key + ': ' + obj[key] + '<br>' ;
            }
        }
    }


    cfdump_toggleRow = function(source) {
        //target is the right cell
        if(document.all) target = source.parentElement.cells[1];
        else {
            var element = null;
            var vLen = source.parentNode.childNodes.length;
            for(var i=vLen-1;i>0;i--){
                if(source.parentNode.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1){
                    element = source.parentNode.childNodes[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(element == null)
                target = source.parentNode.lastChild;
            else
                target = element;
        }
        //target = source.parentNode.lastChild ;
        cfdump_toggleTarget( target, cfdump_toggleSource( source ) ) ;
    }

    cfdump_toggleXmlDoc = function(source) {

        var caption = source.innerHTML.split( ' [' ) ;

        // toggle source (header)
        if ( source.style.fontStyle == 'italic' ) {
            // closed -> short
            source.style.fontStyle = 'normal' ;
            source.innerHTML = caption[0] + ' [short version]' ;
            source.title = 'click to maximize' ;
            switchLongToState = 'closed' ;
            switchShortToState = 'open' ;
        } else if ( source.innerHTML.indexOf('[short version]') != -1 ) {
            // short -> full
            source.innerHTML = caption[0] + ' [long version]' ;
            source.title = 'click to collapse' ;
            switchLongToState = 'open' ;
            switchShortToState = 'closed' ;
        } else {
            // full -> closed
            source.style.fontStyle = 'italic' ;
            source.title = 'click to expand' ;
            source.innerHTML = caption[0] ;
            switchLongToState = 'closed' ;
            switchShortToState = 'closed' ;
        }

        // Toggle the target (everething below the header row).
        // First two rows are XMLComment and XMLRoot - they are part
        // of the long dump, the rest are direct children - part of the
        // short dump
        if(document.all) {
            var table = source.parentElement.parentElement ;
            for ( var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++ ) {
                target = table.rows[i] ;
                if ( i < 3 ) cfdump_toggleTarget( target, switchLongToState ) ;
                else cfdump_toggleTarget( target, switchShortToState ) ;
            }
        }
        else {
            var table = source.parentNode.parentNode ;
            var row = 1;
            for ( var i = 1; i < table.childNodes.length; i++ ) {
                target = table.childNodes[i] ;
                if( target.style ) {
                    if ( row < 3 ) {
                        cfdump_toggleTarget( target, switchLongToState ) ;
                    } else {
                        cfdump_toggleTarget( target, switchShortToState ) ;
                    }
                    row++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cfdump_toggleTable = function(source) {

        var switchToState = cfdump_toggleSource( source ) ;
        if(document.all) {
            var table = source.parentElement.parentElement ;
            for ( var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++ ) {
                target = table.rows[i] ;
                cfdump_toggleTarget( target, switchToState ) ;
            }
        }
        else {
            var table = source.parentNode.parentNode ;
            for ( var i = 1; i < table.childNodes.length; i++ ) {
                target = table.childNodes[i] ;
                if(target.style) {
                    cfdump_toggleTarget( target, switchToState ) ;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cfdump_toggleSource = function( source ) {
        if ( source.style.fontStyle == 'italic' || source.style.fontStyle == null) {
            source.style.fontStyle = 'normal' ;
            source.title = 'click to collapse' ;
            return 'open' ;
        } else {
            source.style.fontStyle = 'italic' ;
            source.title = 'click to expand' ;
            return 'closed' ;
        }
    }

    cfdump_toggleTarget = function( target, switchToState ) {
        if ( switchToState == 'open' )  target.style.display = '' ;
        else target.style.display = 'none' ;
    }

    // collapse all td elements for queries
    cfdump_toggleRow_qry = function(source) {
        expand = (source.title == "click to collapse") ? "closed" : "open";
        if(document.all) {
            var nbrChildren = source.parentElement.cells.length;
            if(nbrChildren > 1){
                for(i=nbrChildren-1;i>0;i--){
                    target = source.parentElement.cells[i];
                    cfdump_toggleTarget( target,expand ) ;
                    cfdump_toggleSource_qry(source);
                }
            }
            else {
                //target is the right cell
                target = source.parentElement.cells[1];
                cfdump_toggleTarget( target, cfdump_toggleSource( source ) ) ;
            }
        }
        else{
            var target = null;
            var vLen = source.parentNode.childNodes.length;
            for(var i=vLen-1;i>1;i--){
                if(source.parentNode.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1){
                    target = source.parentNode.childNodes[i];
                    cfdump_toggleTarget( target,expand );
                    cfdump_toggleSource_qry(source);
                }
            }
            if(target == null){
                //target is the last cell
                target = source.parentNode.lastChild;
                cfdump_toggleTarget( target, cfdump_toggleSource( source ) ) ;
            }
        }
    }

    cfdump_toggleSource_qry = function(source) {
        if(expand == "closed"){
            source.title = "click to expand";
            source.style.fontStyle = "italic";
        }
        else{
            source.title = "click to collapse";
            source.style.fontStyle = "normal";
        }
    }

</script> 
                <table class="cfdump_array">
                <tr><th class="array" colspan="2" onClick="cfdump_toggleTable(this);" style="cursor:pointer;" title="click to collapse">array
                [empty]</th></tr>

            </table>
```

Comment: Can you add the raw response (Response tab) you receive to your question? Also, please include the request and response headers (Headers tab).

Comment: Does it still work correctly in Firefox or IE?

Comment: @mkross1983: IE doesn't have the preview tab that chrome has and I don't use Firefox. While it is possible it might work in Firefox, I am trying to resolve it in Chrome. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: I have attached the Response body to the bottom of the ticket  but it seems to make stackoverflows code parser go wonky as well. Thanks

Comment: No worries, I've fixed the code formatting. I can also confirm this issue, I'll investigate. Incidentally, Firefox does not have this issue.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#resource-previews)  it only renders JSON resources and images. Not sure if this has always been written this way or was changed along with a browser update.

Comment: I'm calling Chrome bug on this one. It's like it's trying to parse the parts of CSS and JS that vaguely resemble JSON into JSON. It makes no sense to me.

Comment: Yeah this is what I suspected. I have sent details of this issue with this page url to Google via the Chrome "Report an issue" section. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: This is still an issue. What is the status?

Comment: @KrunchMuffin: Nope - it's working again in Chrome for a few months now. So they definitely resolved this issue.

Comment: @Cheeky http://i.imgur.com/tTxTJcC.png unless I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @KrunchMuffin: What does it look like in IE? Are you on the latest version of Chrome?

Comment: @Cheeky latest Chrome. Tried Edge and Body > Response Body is same, just HTML.

Answer (score 1):

By setting header status code any but 200 will display html. Can be before or after dump.
`getpagecontext().getresponse().setstatus(406);`
OR
`<cfheader statusCode="406">`

Comment: This worked well for me. It still wont render large dumps ~20k lines of HTML but that has always been the case.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem - using chrome canary as a temporary workaround... https://www.google.co.uk/chrome/browser/canary.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically, chrome knows you are expecting json so it will try to display it that way. its just doing what it thinks you want. i believe you can set it via `<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="text/html">` at the top of your .cfm file.